# Calculating lowest distance point GeoJSON + Mysql + node

Tags: mysql, node.js, math, geojson, haversine

I want to give one point, and another one to collect points, and to order the nearest ones.

Example: There is a point about my house.  I have 50,000 points in my database for supermarkets. I want to order the supermarkets closer to my house.

- I should search for latitude and longitude using the Google Maps API.
- Initially I want to add points using [Mysql + GeoJson](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-geojson-functions.html) (added in
  version 5.7)
- Then [haversine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) to determine the shortest distance. Using nodejs.

If I perform this task for a massive scale of data, I may have performance problems. Right?

I thought of minimizing this cost by creating a where in the query, like for example: consult only supermarkets in my city.

Is this more or less the thought? Can you think of a more plausible solution than that? Remembering that I am a startup, and I have no financial recourse for a paid solution.

Comment: "May have performance problems" - don't optimize prematurely.  Do the calculation, measure, and improve.  Yes, a WHERE class to cut down on the size of the set before you start is a good idea.  If not - parallelize.  The calculations are independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than grabbing all points and sorting you might be able to exploit functions such as ST_Distance_Sphere. For example, ‘find me supermarkets within 10km of my house’.

Here’s an example: http://marcgg.com/blog/2017/03/13/mysql-viewport-gis/